# Problems accessing private data members of a class, that are arrays or vectors of another class

Tags: arrays, class, function, vector, encapsulation

Thanks for viewing my question.

The specific question is: What am I doing wrong here, that is causing the program to crash?

I'm working on a project that takes customer's orders, stores their personal data, and stores their last order.

I've made two classes. Customers and Orders.

Customers contains an array (and before troubleshooting a vector) of Orders.

Below is the code from my project.

from my ohistory.h file:

```
class Order
{
public:
    Order(string* oERROR= new string(""));
    ~Order();
    bool SetOrder(const string& main, const string& drink, const string& side);
    void GetOrder() const;
    void GetError() const;
    string GetMain() const;
    string GetSide() const;
    string GetDrink() const;
private:
    string m_main;
    string m_drink;
    string m_side;
    string* mORDER_ERROR;
};


class Customer
{
public:
    Customer(string* cERROR = new string(""));
    ~Customer();
    void GetName() const;
    bool SetName(const string &fName, const string& lName);
    bool SetAddress(const string& Addr);
    bool SetPhone(const string & pNumber);
    void GetOrder(const int& numOrder) const;
    bool SetOrder(const int& numOrder);
    void GetError() const;



private:
    string m_firstName;
    string m_lastName;
    string m_Address;
    string m_phoneNumber;
    Order m_cOrder[10];
    string* pCUS_ERROR;
    Order askOrder();
};
```

Relevant entries from the ohistory.cpp

```
string Order::GetMain() const
{
    string temp = m_main;
    return temp;
}

string Order::GetDrink() const
{
    string temp = m_drink;
    return temp;
}

string Order::GetSide() const
{
    string temp = m_side;
    return temp;
}

Order Customer::askOrder()
{
    string main, side, drink;

    Order newOrder;
    cout << "***\tEnter a main item: ";
    getline(cin, main);
    cout << "\n***\t\tEnter a side item: ";
    getline(cin,side);
    cout << "\n***\t\tEnter a drink: ";
    getline(cin,drink);

    newOrder.SetOrder(main, drink, side);
    return newOrder;

}

bool Customer::SetOrder(const int& numOrder)
{


    for (int i = 0; i < numOrder; ++i)
    {
        Order temp = askOrder();
        m_cOrder[i].SetOrder(temp.GetMain(), temp.GetDrink(), temp.GetSide());

    }

    return true;
}
```

From main.cpp (call to customer.setOrder() is at the bottom, main calls newCustomer())

```
void newCustomer()
{
    cin.clear();
    char correctCustomerInfo;
    char correctOrder;
    Customer newCustomer;
    string first_name, last_name, address, phone_number;

    do
    {
        cout << "***\tEntering new customer:\n\n";
        cout << "***\t\tFirst Name:";
        getline(cin, first_name);
        cout << "***\t\tLast Name: ";
        getline(cin, last_name);
        cout << "***\t\tAddress: ";
        getline(cin, address);
        cout << "***\t\tPhone Number: ";
        getline(cin, phone_number);
        cout << endl;


        newCustomer.SetName(first_name, last_name);
        newCustomer.SetAddress(address);
        newCustomer.SetPhone(phone_number);

        newCustomer.GetName();
        correctCustomerInfo = askQuestion("Is the user's information correct?");

    } while (correctCustomerInfo != 'y');

    int choice;
    cout <<"***\tPlease enter order:\n\n";
    cout <<"***\tTotal number of Orders:\n";
    cin >> choice;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

    do
    {
        newCustomer.SetOrder(choice);
        correctOrder = askQuestion("Is this the correct order?");
    } while (correctOrder != 'y');


}
```

Dump from VC++ when running debug:

```
'OrderTaker.exe': Loaded 'C:\Documents and Settings\*\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\OrderTaker\Debug\OrderTaker.exe', Symbols loaded.
'OrderTaker.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OrderTaker.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OrderTaker.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'OrderTaker.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
First-chance exception at 0x103157aa (msvcr100d.dll) in OrderTaker.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefee2.
Unhandled exception at 0x103157aa (msvcr100d.dll) in OrderTaker.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefee2.



pUserData   0xfeeefeee  void *
Head    0xfeeefece {pBlockHeaderNext=??? pBlockHeaderPrev=??? szFileName=??? ...}   _CrtMemBlockHeader *
pBlockHeaderNext    CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
pBlockHeaderPrev    CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
szFileName  CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
nLine   CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
nDataSize   CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
nBlockUse   CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
lRequest    CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
      gap   0xfeeefeea <Bad Ptr>    unsigned char [4]

[0] CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
[1] CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
[2] CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
[3] CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
```

The issue happens at:

```
void Customer::SetOrder(const int& numOrder)
{


    for (int i = 0; i < numOrder; ++i)
    {
        Order temp = askOrder();
        m_cOrder[i].SetOrder(temp.GetMain(), temp.GetDrink(), temp.GetSide());

    }


}
```

I'm able to enter in the 3 items, then it crashes.

You may notice a few wonky return type, that was me prepping them for the some steps I plan to do in the future.

Thanks in advance.

===============================EDIT

I figured out my issue. Thanks icepack for sending me in the right direction.

Either way incase someone has a similar issue.

The problem was with the user input I was receiving.

```
int choice;
cout <<"***\tPlease enter order:\n\n";
cout <<"***\tTotal number of Orders:\n";
cin >> choice;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

do
{
    newCustomer.SetOrder(choice);
    correctOrder = askQuestion("Is this the correct order?");
} while (correctOrder != 'y');
```

Instead of sending the user input directly to the class and its data members, I took the input, accessed its value, and reassigned it the same value.

Worked like a charm from there.

Comment: Minimize your code to the relevant minimum. Run it through debugger and point the exact line where it crashes.

Comment: It seemed to compile and run without issue.